# how to set single value and arrays on same edittext in android

Tags: android

I'm getting contacts from the "+" button and retrieving email from MULTIPLE_CHOICE_LIST and getting in array form and setting on edittext, but when i manually write the value in edittext and put "," and then add '+' button to retrive more emails than it replaces the value i have written manually.Please, tell me how to keep the value.
for eg-
abc@gmail.com, and when i retrive from contacts it replaces with an array like [xyz@sdsd.com,qwe@wer.com] and i want it like abc@gmail.com,xyz@sdsd.com,qwe@wer.com
Thanks in advance...

Comment: post your code. its difficult to tell without code.

Comment: better to post your code here to identify your problem.

Comment: Please Post Your Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
String[] emails = {"emai1@abc.com","emai2@abc.com","emai3@abc.com"};
        String finalStr="";
         for (String string : emails) {
            finalStr+=string+",";
        }
          edtEmail.setText(finalStr.substring(0, finalStr.length()-1));
```